# Using the same keywords in many URLs

Tags: seo, links, keywords

I have a service similar to the URL shortening service bit.ly. The link generation method is similar but the site is not. A user uses my site just like the mentioned bit.ly, but I offer a different kind of service for which I want to rank (on Google) for.

If I were to generate links such as: `mysite.com/my-keywords/1Asdf34` would it be considered spammy or black hat?

The same for bit.ly would be: `bit.ly/url-shortening-services/3k1dS4sd` For bit.ly it would defeat the purpose, but URL length in my case does not have to be short.

Comment: Would these URLs that you are generating have content directly on the URL, or would they redirect to some other site (like bit.ly)?

Comment: This is a very similar question to http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/48595/would-this-be-considered-keyword-stuffing-url

Answer (score 0):

IIRC when using a 301 this would have little effect for your site as you are passing the ranking to the page you are linking to. *The amount of PageRank that dissipates through a 301 is currently identical to the amount of PageRank that dissipates through a link.* [Search Engine Land](http://searchengineland.com/google-pagerank-dilution-through-a-301-redirect-is-a-myth-149656)

I am unsure about a 302, but [Moz](http://moz.com/learn/seo/redirection) states that you pass *0% link juice* to the site on the end, but I don't know whether this dissipates or is conferred to the location `http://mysite.com/my-keywords/1Asdf34`.

Comment: Ok, i'm not really sure how does a redirect relate to what i'm asking / generating links to my site.

Comment: @JJ_Jason you said your service is used like bit.ly: bit.ly redirects links.

Comment: My link generation method is similar. There is no redirect, it's a direct link to my site.

Comment: I see, I'll revise me answer in a bit.